# Setting the timer in FreeRTOS for MSP430

Tags: freertos, msp430

Can someone help my to set timer in FreeRTOS for MSP430F5529? I am using minimal project for MSP430F4380, so I have to change it to use with 5529.  Actually, I am using `xTaskGetTickCount()` function, and I need one tick to be 1ms, or 1s.  In `FreeRTOS.config` for 4380 it is set:

```
#define pdMS_TO_TICKS( xTimeInMs ) ( ( TickType_t ) ( ( ( unsigned long ) ( xTimeInMs ) * configTICK_RATE_HZ ) / 1000 ) )

#define configTICK_RATE_HZ ( ( TickType_t ) 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your vApplicationSetupTimerInterrupt implementation which is platform dependent. You should correct the setup of the timer there. Otherwise you could just adjust configTICK_RATE_HZ to match the frequency of the current timer, provided that MSP430F4380 implementation still works on MSP430F5529. The core and the peripherals should be the same so probably only some input clocks are different.